# Blackberry touch fone virtual keyboard keyChar method does not get called

Tags: java, blackberry

I am using a customized Edit Field which overrides Keychar method as follows

```
          protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
        System.out.println(key);
    Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char" + String.valueOf(key));

    if (key == (char) 27 || (key == '\b') || (key == (char) 32)) {
        Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char 1");
        return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
    } else if ((int) key == 13 || (key == '\n') || (key == '1') || (key == '2') || (key == '2') || (key == '3') || (key == '4') || (key == '5')
            || (key == '6') || (key == '7') || (key == '8') || (key == '9') || (key == '0') || (key == ',') || (key == '.') || (key == ';')
            || (key == ':') || (key == '"') || (key == '(') || (key == ')') || (key == '-') || (key == '_') || (key == '+') || (key == '=')
            || (key == '@') || (key == '#') || (key == '$') || (key == '%') || (key == '%') || (key == '}') || (key == '{') || (key == '[')
            || (key == ']') || (key == '*') || (key == '7') || (key == '^') || (key == '>') || (key == '<') || (key == '~') || (key == '`')
            || (key == '!') || (key == '/') || (key == '?')) {
        Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char 2");
        return true;
    }

    if ((int) key == 39 || (int) key == 92 || (int) key >= 123) {
        Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char 3");
        return true;
    }

    if (((int) key >= 65 || (int) key <= 90)) {
        Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char 4");
        return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
    } else if (((int) key >= 97 || (int) key <= 122)) {
        Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char 5");
        return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
    }
    // ascii code for a to z
    // asc11 fo A to Z

    if (!getText().trim().equals("")) {
        setText(Utility.toUpper(getText()));
    }
    Logger.getInstance().logInformationEvent("key char last");
    return true;



}
```

It does not get called when touch screen virtual keyboard is used for input

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: hmm quite a problem.. looking for the solution to same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what could be a solution is to implement `FieldChangeListener` in your custom edit field class, check what last character was inserted and execute your logic around the character inserted. This I think is the only solution that makes sense. But yes, if you are willing to discard a particular character, then you need to change it using `setText()` in EditField but I think it will shoot another `fieldChange` event so try making a boolean check logic to avoid it or may be any other logic, because you would like to avoid the recursive loops.

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){
    String s = getText();
    char cInserted = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
    //put your logic with character here
}
```

The `keyChar` with VirtualKeyboard works only with ENTER key I guess.

I hope it works. Let us know if it does.